# Group by with different select in linq

Tags: c#, linq

**I have the following usecase:**

```
Account Name  |  Ref 1 | Ref 2

Account1      |   Mike | John
Account1      |        |
Account1      |        |
Account2      |   Carl | Mike
Account2      |   Carl | Mike
```

The lines with the same AccountName, Ref1, Ref2 should be merged together, but

> if contains empty Ref1 or Ref2 should not be merged.

**The result should be:**

```
Account Name  |  Ref 1 | Ref 2

Account1      |   Mike | John
Account1      |        |
Account1      |        |
Account2      |   Carl | Mike
```

> AccountViewModel has properties: AccountName, Ref1, Ref2

.

```
var result = new List<AccountViewModel >();

source.GroupBy(vm => new { vm.AccountName, vm.Ref1, vm.Ref2})
                  .Select(group =>
                  {
                      if (group.All(vm => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vm.Ref1)) ||
                          group.All(vm => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vm.Ref2)))
                      {
                          result.AddRange(group);
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          result.Add(new AccountViewModel
                          {                             
                              AccountName = group.Key.AccountName,                             
                              Ref1= group.First().Ref1,
                              Ref2= group.First().Ref2
                          });
                      }
                  });

 return result;
```

Am I missing a feature of GroupBy ? Can it be done in another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three suggestions.

Firstly, you can use `SelectMany` to map each group to a *sequence of items* and have the sequences merged back together for you, rather than using `Select` and having it add to a list as a side-effect.

Secondly, you don't have to check the whole group for null/whitespace - you've already grouped by those values, so they should be identical for each item in the group. You can just check the key.

Thirdly, you don't need to create a new `AccountViewModel` to represent the group if you don't want to - you can just use the first item in the group.

```
return source
    .GroupBy(vm => new { vm.AccountName, vm.Ref1, vm.Ref2})
    .SelectMany(group =>
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(group.Key.Ref1) ||
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(group.Key.Ref2))
            {
                // keep the group separate
                return (IEnumerable<AccountViewModel>)group;
            }
            else
            {
                // just use one item
                return new[] { group.First() };
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking something like this. It assumes `AccountViewModel` implements `IEquatable` for `Distinct` to work.

```
var q = source
          .Where(vm => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vm.Ref1 + vm.Ref2))
          .Distinct()
          .Concat(source.Where(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Ref1 + x.Ref2)))
          .ToList()
```

Comment: You must delete "vm=>" in the Concat function

Answer (score 1):

You can use DistinctBy from MoreLinq. But this is a  little tricky way.

```
using MoreLinq;

//...

var result = source.DistinctBy(x =>
{
    if (x.Ref1 == "" && x.Ref2 == "") return new object();
    return x.AccountName;
}).ToList();
```

You can make this one linear.

```
var result = list.DistinctBy(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Ref1) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Ref2)
   ? new object()
   : x.AccountName).ToList();
```

---

One possible risk that im not sure about. i dont know if this happens or not. but thats a probability so ill tell this. If GC start to collect that objects, it may yield equal objects later when using `new object()`. If im wrong please correct me.

any way you can cast `x` to `object`. in that case this would never happen because `x` is not a trash during this process. (also no items in your list should have equal reference in this case.)

```
if (x.Ref1 == "" && x.Ref2 == "") return (object)x;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think LINQ has a specific GroupBy for your issue.

Because you need some records not to be grouped and some need to be grouped i am thinking you need to split up the query into a grouping query and a normal query for this. and join those results into the result. This may be done within a single query using a .Union

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

source.GroupBy(x => new { x.AccountName, x.Ref1, x.Ref2 }).Select(y => y.Key).ToList()